# How to extract the value from nested list value?

Tags: rust, rust-polars

Given an aggregated dataframe and an index dataframe, how to extract data from the list[<>]?

```
┌──────┬────────────┬───────────┐
│ read ┆ region     ┆ cov       │
│ ---  ┆ ---        ┆ ---       │
│ str  ┆ list[str]  ┆ list[i32] │
╞══════╪════════════╪═══════════╡ df
│ a    ┆ ["x", "y"] ┆ [25, 10]  │
│ b    ┆ ["x", "z"] ┆ [15, 30]  │
└──────┴────────────┴───────────┘

┌──────┬─────────┐
│ read ┆ cov_idx │
│ ---  ┆ ---     │
│ str  ┆ u32     │
╞══════╪═════════╡ df_idx
│ a    ┆ 0       │
│ b    ┆ 1       │
└──────┴─────────┘
```

The following code is an example used to generate the dataframe. The cov is actually generated by a complicated function and df_idx is derived from that (arg_max).

```rust
use polars::prelude::*;
use polars::df;

fn main() -> PolarsResult<()> {
    let df0 = df![
        "read" => ["a", "a", "b", "b"],
        "region" => ["x", "y", "x", "y"],
        "cov" => [25, 10, 15, 30]
    ]?;
    let df = df0.lazy()
        .group_stable([col("read")])
        .agg([col("*")])
        .collect()?;
    let df_idx = df![
        "read" => ["a", "b"],
        "cov_idx" => [0, 1]
    ]?;
}
```

The expected result is

```
┌──────┬───────────┬───────────┐
│ read ┆ region    ┆ cov       │
│ ---  ┆ ---       ┆ ---       │
│ str  ┆ list[str] ┆ list[i32] │
╞══════╪═══════════╪═══════════╡ result_df
│ a    ┆ "x"       ┆ 25        │
│ b    ┆ "z"       ┆ 30        │
└──────┴───────────┴───────────┘
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Lazy API’s `expr.list().get(idx)` to fetch the `idx`th element from each list.

```rust
fn main() -> PolarsResult<()> {
    let df0 = df![
        "read" => ["a", "a", "b", "b"],
        "region" => ["x", "y", "x", "y"],
        "cov" => [25, 10, 15, 30]
    ]?;
    let df_idx = df![
        "read" => ["a", "b"],
        "cov_idx" => [0, 1]
    ]?
    .lazy();

    let df = df0
        .lazy()
        .groupby_stable([col("read")])
        .agg([col("*")])
        .left_join(df_idx, col("read"), col("read"))
        .with_columns(["region", "cov"].map(|c| col(c).list().get(col("cov_idx"))));

    println!("{:?}", df.collect()?);

    Ok(())
}
```

Result:

```
shape: (2, 4)
┌──────┬────────┬─────┬─────────┐
│ read ┆ region ┆ cov ┆ cov_idx │
│ ---  ┆ ---    ┆ --- ┆ ---     │
│ str  ┆ str    ┆ i32 ┆ i32     │
╞══════╪════════╪═════╪═════════╡
│ a    ┆ x      ┆ 25  ┆ 0       │
│ b    ┆ y      ┆ 30  ┆ 1       │
└──────┴────────┴─────┴─────────┘
```